# Escrever datas (mês/ano) entre duas datas

Tags: microsoft-excel, macro

Olá,

Tenho duas datas:

```
Initial     Before
Jan-11      Oct-10
Feb-11      Sep-10
```

Eu gostaria de saber como eu posso ter uma macro que escreva a data entre elas adicionando estas datas em duas novas linhas e procure na tabela preço, o preço pra aquele mês. Eu estou usando VLOOKUP pra isto, mas acho que tem um meio mais eficiente:

```
Initial     Before  Range   Price
Jan-11     Oct-10    Jan-11 0
                     Dec-10 12
                     Nov-10 11
                     Oct-10 10
Feb-11  Sep-10  Feb-11  0
                Jan-11  0
                Dec-10  12
                Nov-10  11
                Oct-10  10
                Sep-10  9
```

Obrigado.

Comment: Tem muitas maneiras de realizar isto, você poderia organizar melhor seu exemplo? Com o código `Vlookup` que é utilizado? E com o exemplo de entrada e saída das funções mais claras, pois não sei se entendi corretamente.

Answer (score 0):

Tente usar a função abaixo para criar a estrutura desejada para a primeira linha e posteriormente adapte o código para rodar com todas as linhas de sua planilha:

```
Sub Escrever_Data()

Dim DATA1 As String
Dim DATA2 As String

    ' Célula Inicial
    Range("A2").Select

    If Selection.Value = "" Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    DATA1 = Selection.Value
    DATA2 = Selection.Offset(0, 1).Value

    ' Copia a primeira data
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.Offset(0, 2).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    ' Verifica se DATA1 < DATA2
    If DateValue(DATA1) < DateValue(DATA2) Then
        MsgBox "Data Inicial menor do que data final", vbError, "Erro"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' Loop para copiar as demais datas
    Do While DateValue(DATA1) <> DateValue(DATA2)

        ' Reduz 1 mês da data inicial
        DATA1 = DateAdd("m", -1, DateValue(DATA1))

        ' Insere nova linha abaixo
        Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
        Selection.EntireRow.Insert
        Selection.NumberFormat = "[$-416]mmm-yy;@"
        'Selection.NumberFormat = "[$-409]mmm-yy;@" ' Se formato em inglês
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = DateValue(DATA1)
    Loop
End Sub
```

Escreva a fórmula que deseja, gravando a macro para saber como faz via vba e depois adiciona na função acima para adicionar a fórmula desejada.

Se postar sua fórmula do `procv` poderemos te ajudar mais facilmente.

Espero ter ajudado!